# Best looking unix distros available freely

Tags: unix, linux-distributions

I wanted to install a new unix based OS on my old machine Pentium 4 processor I was trying to find a better looking distros other than ubuntu. Any recommendations?

Comment: You can configure your desktop, and you can install several desktop environments (xfce, lxde, gnome, cinammon, mate) or window managers (icewm, ratpoison, ...) on your Linux machine. No need to change your distribution!

Answer (score 1):

I really like Chrome OS distro made with Linux. However it depends on you.

[Download Link for Chrome OS](http://getchrome.eu/download.php)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It would be best if you just stick with a particular distro and just change the desktop environments available, if you would be doing this frequently.
There are loads of desktop environments to choose from.